# What does "--" (double dash) mean in this shell command?

Tags: bash

I have this shell command:

```
kill `cat -- $PIDFILE`
```

What the double -- does here? Why not use just

```
kill `cat $PIDFILE`
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `--` tells `cat` not to try to parse what comes after it as command line options.

As an example, think of what would happen in the two cases if the variable `$PIDFILE` was defined as `PIDFILE="--version"`. On my machine, they give the following results:

```
$ cat $PIDFILE
cat (GNU coreutils) 6.10
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Torbjorn Granlund and Richard M. Stallman.

$ cat -- $PIDFILE
cat: --version: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this behavior (while very common) is defined by the receiving program (i.e. `cat`) and not by the shell.

Comment: Is there any documentation or tutorial on writing your own shell script that understands that `--` means the end of command line options? I've seen ones with getopts and other techniques, but nothing discussing `--`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You need not look any further than the [`getopt(1)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt): "Each parameter  after  a  '--' parameter  is  always  interpreted  as  a  non-option  parameter".

Answer (score 1):

**POSIX.1-2017**

[POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/i-never-really-understood-what-is-posix) also specifies it at: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02

> 12.2 Utility Syntax Guidelines
>
> Guideline 10:
>
> The first **--** argument that is not an option-argument should be
>   accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following
>   arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the
>   '-' character.

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash